# Loading Raw XML Into Text View with Mono.Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I'm trying to load Raw XML from a file in my projects assets folder using Mono For Android.

When i press the button I get no errors so the file is clearly being found but the contents aren't loading into the text view. Am I missing something or is my code completely wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var xmlView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.xmlView);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.loadXml);



        button.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            Assets.Open ("XMLFile.xml");

            string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;



            xmlView.Text = "File Loaded!" + xmlcontents;

        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not loading the doc.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(<your doc path>);
```